Output to multiple files when redirecting output during each find -execdir loop
I want to output a single .txt file for a bunch of mp4 or mkv files containing the mediainfo details for each video file.
I am using find and then -execdir to create the mediainfo output, but for all files found it's redirecting to a single file.  The single file contains all of the mediainfo for the x number of mp4/mkv files.  How to I get a Video1.txt and then Video2.txt etc of matching txt files?
Here's my bash line as I have it:
find /mnt/vids/ \( -name '*.mp4' -or -name '*.mkv' \) -execdir mediainfo /mnt/vids/{} > /mnt/vids/{}.txt \;


Do you want to create a single .txt file or one per video or one per directory containing videos, your stated requirements seem to have a few contradictions.

Redirections is done by the shell prior to running the command (here find).
You'd need find to spawn a shell to perform a redirection for each file, or use mediainfo's --LogFile to let it write it itself:
find -H /mnt/vids '(' -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' ')' -type f \
  -exec mediainfo '--LogFile={}.txt' '{}' ';' > /dev/null

(beware not all find implementations support embedding {} inside an argument).
find -H /mnt/vids '(' -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' ')' -type f \
  -exec sh -c '
    for file do
      mediainfo "$file" > "$file.txt"
    done' sh {} +

Those would create a /mnt/vids/path/to/file.mp4.txt with the output of mediainfo for the corresponding /mnt/vids/path/to/file.mp4 file for each file with a name ending in .mp4 or .mkv in or below /mnt/vids.
To create a file.txt instead of find.mp4.txt, that is, replace the mp4/mkv extension with .txt, that would have to be done by the shell:
find -H /mnt/vids '(' -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' ')' -type f \
  -exec sh -c '
    for file do
      mediainfo "$file" > "${file%.*}.txt"
    done' sh {} +

Where ${var%pattern} is a standard parameter expansion operator (originally from the Korn shell) that expands to the value of $var stripped of the shortest string that matches the pattern at the end, so here for ${file%.*} the part from the rightmost occurrence of . to the end of the file path.

Perfect the first option worked perfectly - thank you!
